# Using "called" to modify an entire preceding sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there any possible contexts in which *called* (as a past participle) can be used modifying the whole preceding sentence?

For example:

> "Some people can't recognize whether their behaviors are morally
>   right or not, called the psychopath phenomenon".

1. Is **"called"** modifying **"some people can't recognize whether their behaviors are morally right or not"** ?
2. Can we think that **"which is"** is implied as in **"which is called the psychopath phenomenon"** ?

Comment: Please read on meta: [Titles are for titles](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4797#4797) and [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)

Comment: @J.R. yeap, I'll read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the original sentence and the one that uses *which is* are ungrammatical.

It's the same as making any statement, and then trying to add *called* immediately after it:

> ✘ This apple is delicious, called a Granny Smith.
>   ✘ Some people eat an apple and its core, which is called strange.

But:

> ✔ This apple is delicious, and **it's** called a Granny Smith.
>   ✔ This apple *that is* delicious **is** called a Granny Smith.
>
> ✔ Some people eat an apple and it's core, **which is something other people call** strange.
>   ✔ Some people eat an apple and it's core, **and other people** call **this** strange.
>   ✔ Some people eat an apple and it's core; **other people** call **this** strange.

---

Some versions of the sentence in the question would be grammatical:

> ✔ Some people can't recognize whether their behaviour is morally right or not—*(which is)* **a disorder** called the psychopath phenomenon.
>
> ✔ Some people can't recognize whether their behaviour is morally right or not, and **this** is called the psychopath phenomenon.
>
> ✔ Some people can't recognize whether their behaviour is morally right or not; **this** is called the psychopath phenomenon.
>
> ✔ **People not being able to** recognize whether their behaviour is morally right or not **is** called the psychopath phenomenon.

Comment: Are there really no natural sentences in which "past participle" can refer to its entire preceding sentence?

Comment: @floret Sure, I can think of different sentences that could work that way. Just not the one in your question. For instance: *He staggered down the street in a drunken stupor, hooked on his alcohol habit.* In that sentence, everything after the comma is modifying everything that went before it. But the construction of the sentence is quite different.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I really want to know if there are some natural sentences as well in which "past participle" can refer to the part of its entire preceding sentence.

Comment: Could you tell me why "and this" in your example cannot be replaced with "which"?

Comment: @listeneva *Which* is a pronoun for an item out of a group. There is no group of things in this sentence, so it's not appropriate. Even if (in the US) we allowed *which* to be used as a restrictive clause, there isn't even a general sense of selection here (*the book which I'm reading*) because *some people can't recognize* isn't a noun phrase, so it can't be assigned a quality. Only in the first of my rewritten sentence can *which is* be used, and that's because I've added the noun *a disorder*, which can be assigned a quality (and where *which* makes sense).

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "assigning a quality". As far as I know, the non-restrictive relative pronoun _which_ can refer back to a non-NP antecedent (such as a whole clause or a part of the clause). And your first rewrite clearly proves the point. Now, how does adding _a disorder_ make any difference in the acceptability of the relative construction? If you don't have _which is_, you need _a disorder_ or a similar NP, but if you have _which is_, I think _a disorder_ is optional. Note that _this_ is also a pronoun.

Comment: @listeneva Because a disorder is something you can give a name. You can't give a name to a phrase without describing it *as* a phrase. *✘ "Don't touch that!" which is called an imperative.* *✔ "Don't touch that!" which is **a type of sentence** called an imperative.*

Comment: If so, how come you can leave out _a disorder_ when you use _this_ as in your second and third rewrite?

Comment: @listeneva Because I provided different sentence constructions for comparison. Each sentence represents a different grammatical construction. *A disorder* isn't required in the other constructions. (Although I *could* have used *this disorder*. instead of just *this*.)

Comment: So the reason that you object to the 'which is' construction in the OP's example is not because it's against any grammar rule but because it can be unclear as to what this _which_ (or _this_ for that matter) refers to. If so, I think the 'which is' construction in the OP is more awkward than ungrammatical. That said, I for one have no problem figuring out what _which_ refers to in the OP's example, so I don't even find it terribly awkward.

Comment: @listeneva No, it *is* against grammar rules—insofar as there is such a thing. There are *many* examples of *ungrammatical* sentences that still make sense. This is one of them. The meaning can be *understood* (despite it being quite awkward). That doesn't mean that it's appropriately constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may be grammatically correct (not sure it is), it is somewhat unclear and could be stated in a better way, like with the "which is"

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why it's somewhat unclear? I cannot see anything unclear in the sentence as its context makes the sentence meaning clear even though "which is" omitted.